# changing background color of a webpage

Tags: html, css

I just started writing code recently, about a few weeks ago, so I'm almost brand new to all of this.

I just created my first website and am trying to change the background color because it is still white. This is what I have so far:

```
<style>
    body {font:12px Verdana,Arial; color #428bca; background-color;#5bc0de}
    <h1>
    p
</style>
```

I was also wondering where I could find a list of colors. I know my professor showed us something online that showed a list of colors and their corresponding number.

Comment: What is your question? If it is "this doesn't work", then state that explicitly. Also, what is the `<h1>` doing in the middle of your `style`?

Comment: Change `background-color;#5bc0de` to `background-color:#5bc0de` `:` is used to separate the value from the property. The full correct style would be:  `font:12px Verdana,Arial; color:#428bca; background-color:#5bc0de;` Whie is normally `#FFFFFF` or shorthand `#FFF`

Comment: Also add a colon after `color`.

Comment: For a list of colors, suggest Googling "HTML colors"--did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I want to note there are a few problems in your CSS, for example:

```
background-color;#5bc0de
```

Needs to be:

```
background-color:#5bc0de;
```

Along with this you want a `:` on color: `color: #428bca;`

Colors are in hexadecimal, if you know how it works you can tell what the color is by just looking at it. Think of it like this: `#RRGGBB` , where `RR` be the amount of red in the color. This ranges from `00` being none to `FF` being the most. So for example: *red* (#FF0000), *green* (#00FF00), yellow (#FFFF00), etc.

For CSS you want the format to be like so:

```
[element] { 
     [CSS property]; 
     [another CSS property]; 
     ... ; 
}
```

In other words for element we have tag's such as: `h1`, `p`, `body`, `dic`, etc. And for each CSS property we end it with a semi-colon `;`. So in your code the `<h1>` and `p` don't really need to be there (and you would want `h1` and not `<h1>`). So the correct code would be:

```
body {
    font:12px Verdana,Arial; 
    color: #428bca;
    background-color:#5bc0de;
}
```

While you certainly can find plenty of list [by searching online](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp). It's more important to understand how it works, as I said above in the the `#RRGGBB` example.

Comment: I'm not hugely excited about using SO as a means to crowd-source typo-spotting. Isn't there a better approach? What advice can you give the OP that would help her find such errors herself in the future, or better yet avoid them? Are we expecting that every time her program doesn't work because of a typo she will post it to SO? I'm even less excited about using SO as a human-powered Google replacement for simple queries like "HTML colors".

Comment: @torazaburo Question likes these are mostly closed anyways, since it's a simple typographical error. Although the thing is what I say have already been said better in other places (in CSS tutorials). What I've said the OP might already know (such that it was just typo mistakes). Not to mention small typo's can drive people insane, a second pair of eyes to spot it can be helpful. But helping never hurt anybody, I'll edit my question and give some basic CSS pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the semi-colon with a colon in your style definition.

```
background-color: #5bc0de;
```

Also, if the code is as expressed, remove these lines.

```
<h1>
p
```

There are a multitude of sites that will give you color info.

Here is a popular one:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Comment: Also add a colon after `color`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your CSS (`<h1>` and `p` should be removed). The correct style for `body` is:

```
body {
  font: 12px Verdana, Arial;
  color: #428bca;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
```

CSS is always `property`**:**`value`;

---

A short description of hex colors (eg `#5bc0de`) is, `#RRGGBB` where:

```
R = red
G = green
B = blue
```

Each letters value ranges from `00` up to `FF` in base 16 which describes the intensity of the respective color, so at a quick glance you can tell that `#5bc0de` is going to be more greeny-blue than red. HTML colors can also be represented as:

- `rgb(R,G,B)` same as `#RRGGBB`
- `hsl(H,S%,L%)`  `H = hue [0,360]`, `S = saturation [0,100]`, `L = luminosity[0,100]`
- `#RGB` shorthand for `#RRGGBB`
- `rgba(R,G,B,A)` extended `rgb(R,G,B)` with `A = opacity[0,1]`
- `hsla(H,S,L,A)` extended `hsl(H,S,L)` with `A = opacity[0,1]`
- `color` clear-text word for the color (eg `black`)